# What would the advantages and disadvantages if a computer language always threw an exception when overflow occurred

Tags: language-agnostic, overflow, computer-science

Some computer languages never acknowledge the fact that an overflow has occured, but what would be the advantages of this? I'm assuming the disadvantage of this is that if you have an integer you have certain boundaries that you have to keep in mind.

Comment: Its a part of a question that is on my homework

Comment: We're not doing your homework for you. If you are stuck on something though, folks can offer hints.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm assuming the disadvantage of this is that you if you have a integer you have certain boundaries that you have to keep in mind.

That's not really a disadvantage as you're stating it. If you think about how "overflow" is defined for signed and unsigned addition, though, you may realize that there's a major simplification that can be made if you ignore overflow.

Also, consider performance.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages include catching bugs where a value unintentionally overflows.